# Does $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$ imply $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ mapping?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

This might be a very basic question, but does the function
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}
$$
*necessarily* imply the existence of a function
$$
g:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{R}?
$$
If so, is the reverse implication true, in general?

For example, take $n=m=2$, and $g(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=x_1x_2y_1y_2$. What is $f$ in this case? Take $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)^T$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2)^T$.

If $f$ is not always *constructible*, is there a name for the class of functions that are?

**Edit:** If $g(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$, for example, we have some type of closed-formula for $f$, given by $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}$. In general, however, some representations in terms of vectors might not be possible, and that is my main question. Understandably, none of this should really matter once we see it as a function of all vector components. I am, however, particularly curious about the constructability of such functions when "partitioned" to vector-based components, such as $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ in the example.

Comment: Yes, because $\mathbb{R}^4$ is homeo/iso/whatever you need to $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$.  They are the "same" except for the placement of delimiters.

Comment: If you have $f(a,b,c,d)$ you could write it as $f((a,b),(c,d))$.

Comment: Understood, but would you be able to write an expression for $f(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$ in terms of $\mathbf{u}=(a,b)$ and $\mathbf{v}=(c,d)$? In general, I am not sure how constructible these could be.

Comment: in your example, $f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))\mapsto x_1x_2y_1y_2$

Comment: You are missing that $f$ won't be a function of one variable, I think.  It will also have mutliple inputs. [That, at the end of the day, will be the same as $g$.]  Your $\mathbf{u}$ has multiple slots.

Comment: I see. I will edit the question with a practical example to show what I mean.

Comment: I don't understand your question. f is irrelevant for g and g is irrelevant for f. Take some $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and map everything to it.

Answer (score 2):

I will approach this question in two ways. $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

First, let's consider the simple case of $\R^2 \times \R^2$ versus $\R^4$. You want to know whether a function $f : \R^2 \times \R^2 \rightarrow \R$ always corresponds to a function $g : \R^4 \rightarrow \R$, and vice-versa.

- For the first direction of this correspondence, suppose we have a function $f(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})$, where $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in \R^2$. How do we get a corresponding function $g(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4)$? Simply note that $(z_1,z_2)$ and $(z_3,z_4)$ are elements of $\R^2$, and let $g(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = f((z_1,z_2), (z_3,z_4))$.
- It seems that you are having more trouble with the reverse direction of the correspondence, where we start with a function $g(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$. How do we define the corresponding function $f(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})$? The key is to realize that $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}$, being elements of $\R^2$, each have two components within themselves. That is, there exist unique numbers $x_1,x_2 \in \R$ such that $\textbf{x} = (x_1,x_2)$, and similarly $\textbf{y} = (y_1,y_2)$. Then, you can define $f$ *in terms of these components*, rather than directly in terms of $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}$:
  $$ f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = g(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2). $$
  This is what people do all the time in these situations, and it's mathematically sound. However, you might be unsatisfied by this answer, because I think you really want your formula for $f$ in terms of $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}$ instead of the components. In that case, what you can do is appeal to the *component projections maps*. These are special maps that just pick out one or the other of the components in $\R^2$ (or $\R^n$):
  $$ \pi_1 : \R^2 \rightarrow \R, \text{ given by } \pi_1(x_1,x_2) = x_1 \\ \pi_2 : \R^2 \rightarrow \R, \text{ given by } \pi_2(x_1,x_2) = x_2 $$
  Then, given your function $g$, you can define $f$ by
  $$ f(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}) = g(\pi_1 \textbf{x}, \pi_2 \textbf{x}, \pi_1 \textbf{y}, \pi_2 \textbf{y}). $$
  This is really the same thing as what I presented first, but it makes it more clear that this formula really is in terms of $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}$.

---

Now, the more general approach. You want to have a correspondence between functions $f : \R^n \times \R^m \rightarrow \R$ and functions $g : \R^{n+m} \rightarrow \R$. What you need to do is notice that there is an *isomorphism* between $\R^n \times \R^m$ and $\R^{n+m}$, namely the map
$$ h : \R^{n+m} \rightarrow \R^n \times \R^m \text{ given by } \\ h(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n, z_{n+1}, ..., z_{n+m}) = ((z_1, ..., z_n), (z_{n+1}, ..., z_{n+m})). $$
The fact that this map is an isomorphism means that it has an inverse $h^{-1} : \R^n \times \R^m \rightarrow \R^{n+m}$ (I'll let you think about what this inverse is). Then, the correspondence you want is quite simple.

- Given $f : \R^n \times \R^m \rightarrow \R$, it corresponds to $f \circ h : \R^{n+m} \rightarrow \R$;
- Given $g : \R^{n+m} \rightarrow \R$, it corresponds to $g \circ h^{-1} : \R^n \times \R^m \rightarrow \R$.

This is in fact the same correspondence I described above, put more concisely and generally. $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$

(This can be generalized to the setting of category theory. Indeed, aside from the fact that $X^n \times X^m \cong X^{n+m}$ (which is in fact also true in the setting of abstract categorical products), the above argument can be generalized as follows. For any two isomorphic objects $A,B$, the functions $A \rightarrow C$ are in correspondence with the arrows $B \rightarrow C$. That is, the sets $\Hom(A,C)$ and $\Hom(B,C)$ are isomorphic. This is a result of the fact that $\Hom(-,C)$ is a (contravariant) functor, and functors preserve isomorphism.)